# Makefile same target but different dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a bunch of fortran files that I'm trying to compile with a makefile, and part of the makefile looks like this

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.f  | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(F90) -c -o $@ $< $(FFLAGS) -J $(OBJ_DIR) -I $(OBJ_DIR)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.f90  | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(F90) -c -o $@ $< $(FFLAGS) -J $(OBJ_DIR) -I $(OBJ_DIR)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.F90  | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(F90) -c -o $@ $< $(FFLAGS) -J $(OBJ_DIR) -I $(OBJ_DIR)
```

A you can see, its pretty repetitive, as I have to compile `*.f`, `*.f90` and `*.F90`, but the compilation command is exactly same for all of them. Is there any wat to merge all of them in a single rule?

Comment: I think you re-used the subject line from your previous question: this subject line doesn't seem to match the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You could put the rule inside a variable like this:

```
COMPILE.f90 = $(F90) -c -o $@ $< $(FFLAGS) -J $(OBJ_DIR) -I $(OBJ_DIR)
```

but you still have to write three rules, like this:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.f  | $(OBJ_DIR)
        $(COMPILE.f90)
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.f90  | $(OBJ_DIR)
        $(COMPILE.f90)
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.F90  | $(OBJ_DIR)
        $(COMPILE.f90)
```

If you had lots and lots of these you could create a single rule then eval it multiple times:

```
define COMPILE.f90
$$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $$(SRC_DIR)/%.$(SUFFIX) | $$(OBJ_DIR)
        $$(F90) -c -o $$@ $$< $$(FFLAGS) -J $$(OBJ_DIR) -I $$(OBJ_DIR)
endef

$(foreach SUFFIX,f f90 F90,$(eval $(COMPILE.f90)))
```

but in my opinion it's not worth the extra complexity just for three rules.